# Is it possible, using Ninject, to omit parameters when instantiating a new class?

Tags: ninject

To use Ninject I can do something like the following

```
var kernal = new StandardKernel();
kernal.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var thing = new ThingThatNeedsAWarrior(kernal.Get<IWarrior>());
```

but is it possible, using Ninject, to omit parameters when instantiating a new class?

```
var thing = new ThingThatNeedsAWarrior();
```

when the constructor signature is

```
public ThingThatNeedsAWarrior(IWarrior warrior)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ninject has no effect on `new`. The idea is that you the kernel to instantiate stuff, like so:

```
var thing = kernel.Get<ThingThatNeedsAWarrior>();
```

Then you don't need to specify the arguments. Ninject will choose the constructor with the most parameters it knows how to resolve.

To take things further, ideally, in the application you configure the kernel and then you do something like:

```
var applicationRoot = kernel.Get<ApplicationRoot>();
```

and have all objects of your appplication instantiated in one go (as dependencies of `ApplicationRoot`).

Mark Seeman also has a blog post about where/how to configure the DI: [CompositionRoot](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). He's also got quite a few more on the usage of DI containers.

(Thanks @NighOwl888 for the correction).

Comment: also, consider using an Abstract Factory to handle the construction of `ThingThatNeedsAWarrior`

Comment: That's great, I think it has been my blind use of Ninject with MVC controllers that has skewed my understanding.  I really like the CompositionRoot approach and it's good to know that Ninject will create dependencies it knows about.  Thanks

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit - Technically speaking, a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) is the part where you create the DI container instance and register the types. What you have labeled `applicationCompositionRoot` is in fact an application's ***object graph*** (or at least from what I gather based on your description).

Comment: @NightOwl888 oh yeah, you're right. I got a bit confused because it's the *root* of the *object graph*, but you're right it's not the *composition root*. Going to edit it.